# Why do we use Base View and Base Presenter for MVP pattern?

Tags: android, android-mvp

in MVP (Model View Presenter) pattern using base view and presenter is common practice. Can we omit them? and why do we use it at the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind using `BaseView` and `BasePresenter` is to move common methods across child to parent, for suppose most of your views have `showProgress()` method , you can stop declaring it in each child and move to parent as in

```
interface BaseView{
  void showProgress();
}

interface SomeView extends BaseView{
  void someAction();
}

interface OtherView extends BaseView{
  void otherAction();
}

interface NoProgressView { // this view doesn't need progress so avoid extedning
  void dummyAction();
}
```